# Why this recursive function won't work

Tags: scala, recursion

I have this function to calculate `x` to the power of `n` recursively:

```
def pow(x:Double,n:Int):Double={
    if (n==0) 1
    else if (n<0) 1/pow(x,-n)
    else if (n%2 == 1) x*pow(x,n-1)
    else pow(pow(x,n/2),2)
}
```

But this won't work for the last case properly (i.e. positive even numbers). It just hangs there.
However if I give this:

```
def pow(x:Double,n:Int):Double={
    if (n==0) 1
    else if (n<0) 1/pow(x,-n)
    else if (n%2 == 1) x*pow(x,n-1)
    else {val y=pow(x,n/2); y*y}
}
```

It runs as expected. Can anyone tell me what makes the first implementation wrong. I am attempting to answer Question 10 from Chapter 2 of the book *Scala For Impatient*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your method at some point you end up doing:

```
pow(pow(x,1),2) -> pow(x*pow(x,0),2) -> pow(x,2) -> pow(pow(x,1),2) -> ...
```

This is because n==2 is only handled by the last condition which ends up calling itself over and over again...

Answer (score 2):

You always call `pow(...,2)` in the last case, and the last case is the only one that handles `n==2`.  So....